# Capybara have_content() not showing as expected

Tags: rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok, I'm at my wits end. I have a feature spec and it's not passing. 
The deleting_posts_spec.rb is not finding the text "Post was successfully destroyed." I've inspected the page and on my localhost the success notice text is most definitely there. I've tried inserting a byebug and when I run page.body, while in byebug, I can see the code for the notice and when I actually delete something, I can see the notice. The odd part is, I have another test for creating_posts and the success notice does show and the test passes.

Weird, right?

I don't have turbolinks because that was causing odd errors before. I've taken out the redirect in the controller as well, but still no notice. I recently bundle updated, but still failing. My ruby version is 2.3.1 and RSpec is 3.5.4.

Let me know if you need additional info.

My error

```
Deleting Posts admins can delete posts
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Post was successfully destroyed."
       expected to find text "Post was successfully destroyed." in "Listing All Posts Content Author Actions Post Something"
```

**Update!** I changed my code in the delete spec, but I'm still getting the same failure. I commented out what was originally there for reference.

deleting_posts_spec.rb

```
RSpec.feature "Deleting Posts" do
   let(:administrator) {Administrator.create(name: "My Name", email: "my@example.com", password: "password" )}

   let(:post) {Post.create!(content: "The Content created", votes: 1, story: "My story", author: "A Name")}

     scenario "admins can delete posts" do
     login(administrator)

     click_link "Admin Page"

     #page.all("tr.the-actions").each do |tr|
       click_on "Delete" if page.has_selector?('a[href*="delete-link"]')
         #.to change(Post, :count).by(-1)
     #end

    expect(page.current_path).to eq(admin_posts_path)
    expect(page).to have_content "Post was successfully destroyed."
  end
end
```

admin/posts_controller.rb

```
def destroy                                                                                                                            
  if @post.destroy
    redirect_to admin_posts_path
    flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully destroyed.'
  end
end
```

views/admin/posts/index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>                                                                                                         

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
       $('#notice').remove();
     }, 2000);
   })
 </script>

 <center><h1>Listing All Posts</h1></center>

  ...
  stuff
  ...

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr class="the-actions">
      <td><center><%= post.content %></center></td>
      <td><center><%= link_to post.author, post_path(post.id) %></center></td>
      <td class="actions-column">
        <%= link_to 'Show', post %> &middot;
        <%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, :admin, post], class: "edit-link"  %> &middot;
        <%= link_to 'Delete', [:admin, post], method: 'delete', confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this post?', class: "delete-     link" %>                                                                                                                                 
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: could be a race condition, try to `sleep(5)` after `expect(page.current_path).to eq(admin_posts_path)`. If not, try it with `selenium` and keep the sleep call to see if the message actually pops up. Last resort would be to `tail -f log/test.log` to see if DELETE fails

Comment: @Dimitry_N Thanks for the quick response! I tried ```sleep(5)```, but it didn't work. I'm attempting your other suggestions now.

Comment: Why do you have `if page.has_selector?` in your test  - you should know whether or not there is going to be a `Delete` link/button on the page, otherwise the test is pointless.  Additionally never use the `eq` matcher with current_path - use the provided have_current_path matcher - `expect(page).to have_current_path(admin_posts_path)`.  Beyond that what driver are you using? If using a JS capable driver you need to handle the confirm box that will pop up when you click the link

Comment: Good question. The reason I have page.has_selector? is because the test fails saying, it couldn't find the "Delete" link when I don't have `page.has_selector'. Currently, my "Delete" link is within a `tbody` and having simply, `click_on "Delete"` was failing. I'll make the change to `have_current_path`. Thank you for the suggestion. Sorry, by driver you mean?

Comment: @kyle There are a few drivers that Capybara can use, some are headless, some support JS, etc.  If you don't know, you're probably using rack_test which doesn't support JS and doesn't process most CSS - it's really only useful for very basic testing - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment above with a few comments about your test but I think the main reason it's not working is that the Post object isn't actually created when you go to the page.  When using `let` the objects are lazily created when you first reference them, but your test never references `post` so it's never created.  You can fix that by using `let!` instead

```
let!(:post) {Post.create!(content: "The Content created", votes: 1, story: "My story", author: "A Name")}
```

which will always create the object.  This would have been obvious if you didn't have the `if page.has_selector?('a[href*="delete-link"]')` code in your test since Capybara would have told you it couldn't find the 'Delete' link/button

Comment: YES! That was it! My misunderstanding was that since "Delete" was in a column, I had to use `page.has_selector?` in order to click it. With your solution, it passes! Thank you for explaining. I'm fairly new to `let` and `let!`.

Comment: All `page.has_selector?` does is return true or false based on whether a matching element exists.  It should be very rarely used when testing apps since you control all the data and should know whether or not elements are going to be there -- It would mostly be used if writing something like a scraper using Capybara.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!